# Can't pass callback function to SocketIO in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io

**Stack:** Node.js + Express + TypeScript + Socket.io

**Problem:** I cannot transfer the callback provided in the library using TypeScript
How do I call the callback correctly? The code below throws an error.

```
socket.on('method', async (params: any, callback: (res: any) => void) => {
  // endpoint's logic
  const result = await this._service.ServiceMethodAsync(params);

  // acknowledgement
  callback(result);
})
```

Error

> TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: Can you add your implementation where you emit the ```method``` event.

Comment: needless to edit the question here your comment actually made me think about checking the client-side code and turns out the snippet mentioned above is just fine and there was a problem with emitting the method. thank you.

Comment: Nevertheless, please provide the implementation and cause of the issue, then post the answer so that the developers that have the same issue can see your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing validation on the event that has triggered on the socket then I would say follow the example provided on their page [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/listening-to-events#Validation).

In the case you have provided above you would have:

```
socket.on('method', async (params, callback) => {
  if (typeof callback !== "function") {
    // event is not an acknowledgement, do something i.e. return
    return;
  }

  const result = await this._service.ServiceMethodAsync(params);

  // acknowledgement
  callback(result);
})
```

Here is another resource on understanding [Acknowledgements](https://socket.io/docs/v3/emitting-events#Acknowledgements) in SocketIO.

Answer (score 0):

checking the client-side code and turns out the snippet mentioned above is just fine and there was a problem with emitting the method.

fixed client:

```
socket.emit('method', msg, (res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```